# Extjs callback function to controller

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I have the following base class which handles all request

```
makeRequest: function(mydata) {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: './handler.php',
        method: 'GET',
        scope: this,
        params: {
            data: mydata
        },
        callback: this.myResponse,
        success: function(xhr, params) {
            console.log('Success');
        },
        failfure: function(xhr, params) {
            console.log('Failure');
        }
    });
}
```

In my controller I have

```
.............
requires: [
  'Test.libs.Request'
],

............
onItemClick: function() {
  var objCallback = Ext.create('Test.libs.Request', {
    scope: this
  });
  objCallback.makeRequest(1);
},

myResponse: function(options, success, response) {
    console.log(response);
}
```

After success executes, how can I get to the controller's myResponse as a callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass along the fn and the scope, something like:

```
Ext.create('Test.libs.Request', {
    callback: this.myResponse
    scope: this
}); 

// You need to get a reference to those passed params inside your request method.
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: './handler.php',
    method: 'GET',
    scope: passedScope,
    params: {
        data: mydata
    },
    callback: passedCallback
});
```

Comment: For the moment, I passed parameters to objCallback.makeRequest(1,this.myResponse,this) for callback and scope and it works.

Comment: Yeah, that will do it.